# PhoneGap 3.3 iOS KeyboardShrinksView

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In PhoneGap/Cordova 3.3 (and 3.2) the preference **KeyboardShrinksView** for iOS is gone and has been replaced with **enableViewPortScale**.

Can anyone explain to me how to achieve the same result I would get with KeyboardShrinksView but by using enableViewPortScale and the **viewport** Metatag?

When in iOS, if the user opens the keyboard I need the entire view to shrink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, height=device-height"/>
```

Thanks to @daniel-miller, the answer above came from him here:

[Keyboard hides iOS input fields in PhoneGap Build 3.1 with an iFrame/object and JQTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576401/keyboard-hides-ios-input-fields-in-phonegap-build-3-1-with-an-iframe-object-and/21759058#21759058)

Other Help:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/87K3lYr6f40

Comment: I had a problem, that when after the keyboard has shown. The view got bigger than the screen so I had horizontal scroll.. This solved it thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The commit that removes these (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4978) states:

> The Keyboard preferences have been removed from core and put into its own plugin in cordova-labs plugins branch.

I've tracked this down to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard and this fork (?): https://github.com/etiennea/phonegap-keyboard

This should then allow you to use

```
Keyboard.shrinkView(true)
```

in your JS to minic the old functionality of KeyboardShrinksView

Comment: While I gave you an upvote, I cannot accept as the answer. It does help, but the question was to achieve this result in the new manner. Thanks for the links though!! :D

Comment: the ```Keyboard.shrinkView(false);``` and ```Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);``` seem to have no effect at all on iOS 8.1 with latest cordova... Is there any specific setting to make it work ?

Comment: Just noticed the same. Was going to look for enableViewPortScale.

Comment: shrinkView has no effect on iOS 7 or greater, as it disregards the shrinkView with a if(!IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"7.0")) in the code. As for the hideFormAccessoryBar(true) works fine for me. But note that you wrote false in your comment.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for iOS >= 7? height=device-height doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am also looking for a fix for iOS >= 7

Comment: Same here... I also need a fix for >=7